# Youtube Playlist in Video.js

Tags: youtube, video.js, playlist

I'm trying to build a playlist of YouTube URLs using [Video.js](https://github.com/videojs/video.js), and 2 plugins for Video.js: [videojs-playlists](https://github.com/jgallen23/videojs-playLists) and [videojs-youtube](https://github.com/eXon/videojs-youtube). Everything is included correctly and working nicely when each plugin is used individually. However, when I try to use the playlist plugin to play a list of YouTube URLs, I get the video loading wheel in FF (which never ends!) and in Chrome, the opening frame is loaded but the Play button is unresponsive. Firebug shows no errors in the code, yet clearly something is stalling somewhere. Here's the relevant code:

HTML:

```
video id="video" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls data-setup='' width="640" height="264"></video>
<h1></h1>
<button type="button" data-action="prev">Previous</button>
<button type="button" data-action="next">Next</button>
```

And my JS:

```
var videos = [
{
src : [
  'http://stream.flowplayer.org/bauhaus/624x260.webm',
  'http://stream.flowplayer.org/bauhaus/624x260.mp4',
  'http://stream.flowplayer.org/bauhaus/624x260.ogv'
],
poster : '',
title : 'Whales'
},
{
src : [
  'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3sWPKAbQZVM'
],
poster : 'http://www.videojs.com/img/poster.jpg',
title : 'Ocean'
 }
 ];
var options = { "techOrder": ["youtube", "html5", "flash"] };
//var options = { "techOrder": ["youtube"] , "src" : "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GaMcsKtBDwE"}; //Single works - but not with playlist
var player = videojs('video', options);
  player.playList(videos, {
  getVideoSource: function(vid, cb) {
  cb(vid.src, vid.poster);
    }
  });
  $('[data-action=prev]').on('click', function(e) {
    player.prev();
  });
  $('[data-action=next]').on('click', function(e) {
    player.next();
  });

});`
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried these plugins recently and I found the problem.

The problem is here:

```
getVideoSource: function(vid, cb) {
  cb(vid.src, vid.poster);
}
```

Make sure you set the first value for the cb method is a link string instead of an object.
(ex:'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=videoID')

Good luck :)